# Google Sign-In on iOs can not be recorded using xCode UI Testing Inspector, perhaps accessibility not supported

Tags: ios, google-signin, xcode-ui-testing

I'm using xCode UI Testing Inspector to write my automated UI tests for an iOs app.
For an unknown reason, the Inspector can not record steps during Google Sign-In on my app.
Did somebody faced with such problem?
I've noticed, that the UI Testing tool use Accessibility API to get access to controls.
So, If this tool can not work with Sign-in elements, then Sign-in not support accessibility instruments.

Here is the test code:

```
 func testSignIn() {

 let app = XCUIApplication()
```

//welcome tour skipped, UI inspector succesfully found all elements

```
 XCUIApplication().scrollViews.otherElements.buttons["google sign in buttom"].tap()
```

//here should be click on a google account, which I've select, but there are no code have been recorded

Comment: Can you post the code in question you're struggling with?

Comment: Yep, sure. I've added the code.